# Getting Day Names from String in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've used Ruby's Date::DAYNAMES function to save my days in a string using checkboxes.

```
- Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index do |day,index|
  = check_box_tag "promotion[days_#{index}]", index, false, :name => "promotion[days][]", :checked => (@promotion.days.include? index.to_s)
  = day
```

Which gives a string like this:

```
 "---\n- '0'\n- '1'\n- '4'\n"
```

In my view, I've tried using the following to display the day names but can't get all of them. Only ever the first day.

```
 = Date::DAYNAMES[@promotion.days.to_i]
```

Can someone show me how to get each selected day name out please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string looks like yaml. Try this in irb:

```
require 'date'
require 'psych'

Psych.load("---\n- '0'\n- '1'\n- '4'\n").map { |i| Date::DAYNAMES[i.to_i] }

=> ["Sunday", "Monday", "Thursday"]
```